# Scala Test - Code with Await ignore the mocked future

Tags: scala, unit-testing, future, scalatest

I'm writing unit tests for a service method that returns a Future[Boolean].
Inside the code that I'm testing, there is an Await.result usage on a sequence of future.
class serviceLogic, method logic: Future[Boolean] -

```
val futureList: List[Future[Model]] = iterator.map { item => 
    val handleResult: Future[Model] = handlerService.handle(item)
    // do some logic
    handleResult
}.toList

Await.result(Future.sequence(futureList), 1 minute)
// some logic
```

In the unit test that I'm writing, I'm mocking the handlerService to return a Future.successful for the handle method and I do see that it returns a successful result, but in the test, the Await.result waits till the duration ends and it ignores the mock of the calls, as the future didn't finish.
**While having the same test that returns a Future.failed(new RuntimeException), this is working as expected and the Await.result returns immediately**

The test with the Future failed that works as expected:

```
"Some operation" should "should fail if handle failed" {

    val someModel = Model()

    when(handlerServiceMock).handle(anyString())
        .thenReturn(Future.failed(new RuntimeException))
   
    serviceLogic.logic().map { result =>
        result mustBe false
    }
}
```

But, this is not working for a successful future. the test looks like that:

```
"Some operation" should "should succeed if handle succeeded" {

    val someModel = Model()

    when(handlerServiceMock).handle(anyString())
        .thenReturn(Future.successful(someModel))
   
    serviceLogic.logic().map { result =>
        result mustBe true
    }
}
```

The test fails as it waits for the duration.
I do see in debug that for each handle the return is as expected Future(Success(model)), but the Future.sequence(futureList) is Future(not completed), so this is not working properly or I'm missing something...
Can you please help?

Comment: Show us your test ;)

Comment: @GaëlJ sorry, added the test code that didn't work for me.

Comment: Do you pass the mocked service to class constructor during instantiation or does the tested class is injected by framework?

Comment: The issue most likely is that instance of `handlerService` used inside the `logic` call is not the `handlerServiceMock` you create in the test.

Comment: When I'm debugging it, I do see that in the response from the handlerService.handle I'm getting a Future(Success(model)). But for some reason, the Await is not finished immediately.

When I'm duplicating the test method and return a Failure Future instead of success. It's working!
Future.failed(new RuntimeException)

Any idea why the success is not working as expected?

Comment: I also noticed in debug, that the Future.sequence(futureList) is "Future(<not completed>)" and the value is Nill! while in the other test, where the mock is Future.failure, the Future.sequance looks completed with failure and the value is as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if the mock is only returning that for the first call.  The failed future will short-circuit the `sequence`.

Comment: It looks like the mock of the handle is returned as expected, for the times that the test is expected.. for example, if the list has 2 items, then the returned mock from the handle is twice of Future.success or Future.failed